# DataInputStream readByte is returning a big value

Tags: java, file, byte, datainputstream

I'm creating a Chip-8 emulator that requires you to read virtual rom files in bytes. I have this code that is calling a readByte method. If you look at the values that this is printing out, some of them are regular bytes, and some of them are crazy big.[image]

Comment: Don't be afraid to tell me if i'm leaving out any info!

Comment: In order to increase readability you should write your code rather than screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataInputStream.readByte()` returns a `byte` which is a *signed type*. The returned value can be *negative*.

`Integer.toHexString(intValue)` returns a hex-representation of the value interpreted as an ***unsigned*** integer.

Thus, positive values (like 76, 12) are printed as you expect, while negative values are printed in [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (the way negative values are represented in Java).

For example, the printed value of `fffffffe` is a 32-bit (integer size) two's complement representation of `-2`.

---

To properly print byte values, use this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02x", tmp));
```

Note that this will also properly left-pad printed values with zeros.

Comment: I think printing bytes by their hex values is more useful for file format work (header bytes etc)... However Asker should really clarify if they want the hex values or decimal values.